# Can't change excerpt length and more tag

Tags: functions, filters, excerpt, read-more

I tried to change the excerpt length and the more tag the way it is described in the codex:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 10;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );


function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '[.....]';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

this is how I call the excerpt from within the template:

```
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
```

But it still has the same length and more tag as before. How can that be?

Comment: Are you adding excerpt in excerpt meta field?

Comment: No. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Yes it makes difference. See answer for more info.

Comment: Where are you adding the above two filters ( in which file )?

Comment: In functions.php.

Comment: Then it should work can you show me your while code by copying it in to pastebin.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Ebd3XHpz

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10481/discussion-between-vinod-dalvi-and-lord-mord)

Answer (score 0):

[excerpt_length](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_length)  filter does not work on manually added filter so you use [wp_trim_excerpt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_excerpt) function, you can develop code same as following to achieve it.

```
<?php
if( has_excerpt() ){
    the_excerpt();
} else {
    wp_trim_excerpt();
}
?>
```

[excerpt_more](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_more)  does not work on WordPress version  2.8.x and Older for those versions you have to use following filter.

```
<?php
function new_excerpt_more( $excerpt ) {
return str_replace( '[...]', '...', $excerpt );
}
add_filter( 'wp_trim_excerpt', 'new_excerpt_more' );
?>
```

Comment: I'm using WP 3.6. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: @Lord_Mord Are you checking it on search or archive page? Because i checked your code in pastebin and you have added is_search() || || !is_single() condition